# Selenium - How to Wait?

Tags: selenium, php-webdriver

I need to be able to wait for *one of multiple things* that could happen to a page after a certain action is taken. Examples of these things are: URL changes, a certain title is set, certain content on the page appears, etc.

This explains how to wait - https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait. However, I need to be able to wait for multiple things at the same time. I want the waiting to stop once one of the conditions occur.

Is there a way to "or" during a wait (e.g. wait for URL to change **OR** title contains "foo" **OR** "bar" appears on the page, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same link you posted, look for the "Custom conditions" section, i.e.:

```php
$driver->wait()->until(
    function () use ($driver) {
        $elements = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('li.foo'));

        return count($elements) > 5;
    },
    'Error locating more than five elements'
);
```

Note the use of `findElements` in the code example. When nothing is found, an empty array will be returned. If only one of three elements must be visible, you do something like:

```php
$driver->wait()->until(
    function () use ($driver) {
        $elements1 = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('li.foo1'));
        $elements2 = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('li.foo2'));
        $elements3 = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('li.foo3'));

        return count($elements1) + count($elements2) + count($elements3) > 0;
    },
    'Error locating at least one of the elements'
);
```